# Adding rows/getting rid of rows to table if checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor

I want to get rid of rows/add rows based on the action of my 'CheckBox'

Here is my Jquery

```js
<script>

    function doalert(checkboxElem) {
        if (checkboxElem.checked) {
            // if row is checked add 2 additional rows of the row shown
        } else {
            // if checkbox is unchecked remove the 2 additional rows
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here is my row

```html
<tr>

    <td>
        @part.PartIDLink
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" onchange="doalert(this.id)" checked>
    </td>
    @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
    {
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
    </td>
    }
</tr>
```

As requested by a user, here is the rendered HTML

```
<table class="table">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <th>
                                IGT Part ID
                            </th>                        
                            <th>
                                Part Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Qty used in Item
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Move All
                            </th>                           
                            <th style="color:blue">
                                Transfer
                            </th>
                            <th style="color:forestgreen">
                                Harvest
                            </th>
                            <th style="color:red">
                                Dispose
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tr>

                                <td>
                                    <a p-id="346" style="color:#FF00FF;" href="#">600601</a>
                                </td>                               
                                <td>
                                    Supply - Packing Carton, 9" x 8" x 8", MU/AX
                                    <input id="Parts_0__PartName" name="Parts[0].PartName" type="hidden" value="Supply - Packing Carton, 9&quot; x 8&quot; x 8&quot;, MU/AX">
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold">
                                    1
                                    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field QtyInItem must be a number." data-val-required="The QtyInItem field is required." id="Parts_0__QtyInItem" name="Parts[0].QtyInItem" type="hidden" value="1">
                                 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                               <input type="checkbox" id="all346" onchange="doalert(this.id)" checked="">
                                </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedActionType field is required." id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Transfer">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Harvest">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Dispose">
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
```

I essentially want that row to be duplicated twice. The purpose of this is for example, if there are 5 parts in an item, I want the user to be able too dispose of 2, harvest 2, and transfer 1 if they want too.

How can I accomplish this?

**Note** it's important that this is done for only the specific part ID and not for every single part.

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML code or create snippet/demo with relative code

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef As requested, I have added in the rendered html to my question